# Read Tree Menu Xml C#

Tags: c#, xml

Hello i need parse this xml with C# in console app , any help ?

```
    <TREE_MENU_NESTED>
 <TREE>Category I
     <TREE ACTION="URL" LINK="c1/p1.html" TARGET="_self" ICON="icon_slide" >Product 1</TREE> 
     <TREE ACTION="URL" LINK="c2/p2.html" TARGET="_self" ICON="icon_slide" >Product 2</TREE> 
 </TREE>
 <TREE>Category II
     <TREE ACTION="URL" LINK="c2/p1.html" TARGET="_self" ICON="icon_slide" >Product 1</TREE> 
     <TREE ACTION="URL" LINK="c2/p2.html" TARGET="_self" ICON="icon_slide" >Product 2</TREE> 
 </TREE>
 </TREE_MENU_NESTED>
```

Need show in console:
--category 1: product1, product 2

--category 2: product1, product 2

Comment: What do you mean, "parse"? What are you trying to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try [this](http://bit.ly/IA4NQT)

Comment: need to show category 1 - product 1 , product 2 ... category 2... category 3 etc

Comment: @mbarrerar I think that no one will give you a complete answer to your question. Try something and then post a question in the point you stuck. :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq to Xml

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse("You XML text");

foreach (XElement treeNode in doc.Elements())
    Console.WriteLine(treeNode.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks Any option to find root category to show --category 1: product1, product 2

Answer (score 0):

using linq2xml :

```
XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse("<TREE_MENU_NESTED>... ");
Console.WriteLine(xmlTree);
```

Comment: thanks! any option to foreach xmlTree  node by node and display category 1 - product 1 , product 2